# how to stop reloading of a page on go back in ionic 3 angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have two pages(page1 & page2), on page1 there are two iframe in which pre define urls are loaded then I navigate to page2 and as come back to page1 from page2, both the iframe start reloading.

I want to stop this reloading of iframe. Is this possible in ionic?

Answer (score 1):

try to put your code in "ngOnInit" or in page "constructor" if you have used ionViewWillEnter. This is called only once the page is initiated.

Also try to ignore NavController push function while navigating from page2 to page1. use ionic default back button or use the NavController Pop function to navigate from page 2 to page 1.

Comment: one more thing,  If both the iframe shift to page2 and then I navigate to page1->page2(load iframe)->page1->page2. can I stop reloading of iframe on page2 in this case.

Comment: No, Because every time when you navigate to page 2 from page 1 you will use NavController Push function and in such case your constructor and ngOnInit will be called so this will not be possible with ionic nav stack. By the way if you think  answer is useful i would ask you to please Vote Up.

Comment: Second case can be possible,  when set page2 as root page on navigate to this page. And you can navigate to any other page from page2 by 'NavController.push()'. When wants to come back to page second just use 'NavController.popToRoot()'.So page second not reload in this way.

Comment: yeah it seems like it can work. you can give it a try i am not sure

Comment: By the way can you mark it as answer so that other can see it and use it